# browser back button doesn't work on named anchor in overflow: visible div

Tags: css, button, overflow, anchor, back

I have named anchors and they take me correctly, however when i press the back button of the browser it doesn't take me on top of the screen. I have narrowed the issue to a css overflow: auto in #divScreen css section.

HTML ( pastebin ) : http://pastebin.com/aRvtBzCt
CSS ( pastebin ) : http://pastebin.com/Qkkiz98x

anyone knows what is going on, and how to solve ? the problem is persistent among all major browsers ( firefox, chrome, opera ).

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head>      <link href="index2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  </head> <body>      <div id="divScreen">            <div id="divFAQ" class="cCommonDivs">                               <span id="spanFAQTitle" class="cPagesTitle">Frequently Asked Questions</span>               <p></p>             <div id="divFAQQuestions" class="cBigLinks">                    <ul>                        <li><a href="#aQ1b" id="aQ1h">Q1</a><br/></li>                      <li><a href="#aQ2b" id="aQ2h">Q2</a><br/></li>                      <li><a href="#aQ3b" id="aQ3h">Q3</a><br/></li>                      <li><a href="#aQ4b" id="aQ4h">Q4</a><br/></li>                  </ul>               </div>              <p></p><hr/>                <div id="divFAQAnswers" class="cPagesText">                 <a class="cQuestion" id="aQ1b">Q1</a><br/>                  <div id="divAns1">                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   </div>                  <a class="cQuestion" name="aQ2b" id="aQ2b">Q2</a><br/>                  <div id="divAns2">                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   </div>                  <a class="cQuestion" name="aQ3b" id="aQ3b">Q3</a><br/>                  <div id="divAns3">                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   </div>                  <a class="cQuestion" name="aQ4b" id="aQ4b">Q4</a><br/>                  <div id="divAns4">                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                   </div>              </div>          </div>      </div>              </body></html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#divScreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    visibility: visible;
}

.cCommonDivs {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 100px;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #4D7094;
    border: 3px solid #D5E5FF;
    border-color: #000000;  
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.cBigLinks a {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cBigLinks a:hover {
    color: #FFFF00;
}

.cPagesTitle {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFFF00;
}

.cPagesText {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cQuestion {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;    
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: I actually posted the code relevant to the question, it's the two links in pastebin. Here is the jsfiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/5fh3W/

Comment: If by any chance pastebin goes down tomorrow, no one can answer your question. Please insert the relevant code **in the question body**. A code block is indented by 4 spaces (or by highlighting it and pressing CTRL+K).

Comment: Okay, added the code here as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The back button is simply not designed to revert to old positions in the same file in a scrollable div.

If you want to follow a link and have the back button bringing you to the old position, you have two solutions :

- link to a different page and use javascript to scroll the div (based on a URL parameter)
- harder (especially to maintain) but interesting : manipulate the browser history using the history API ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history ). This solution is usually chosen for ajax applications where some content is dynamically loaded. Be careful as you'll encounter browser compatibility limitations.

Comment: dystroy, that is not true. the back button DOES take you to the previous position: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html go there and click on any of the TOC links and then click the back browser button. it will take you on top of the page

Comment: You're right. What I said was only correct for scrollable divs.

Comment: I see, that is a pitty, and I wouldn't like to use javascript for such a simple functionality. I will see if I can change the structure of the page to make it work without a scrollable div. Thank you